# Slow collision detection at low frame rates

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I'm experiencing an odd issue with my collision detection. I'm using the Update method to move the player (I don't want to use FixedUpdate because that creates an undesired weird movement). The fixed timestep is set at the default 0.02 (I tried playing with time setting but that didn't work either) . I set the collision detection of the rigidbodies of both objects to "continuous dynamic". Also, I set the target frame rate to 300 and that didn't change anything...

When the framerate is low or the device itself is slow, the collision detection doesn't always work. The player can easily fall through the object it's supposed to collide with, though sometimes it doesn't.

Please tell me what I can do to fix this because I've published a game and many users are reporting this (serious) bug. Thank you for your support.

This is what is supposed to happen:

[image]

This is what actually happens:

[image]

(as you can see, the cube gets out of the wall and to the other side)

I move the player when the user releases the mouse button:

Script 1:

```
public Script2 Jumper;
public float TimeToJump;

public void Update()
{
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) 
    {
            StartCoroutine (Delay (1f/50f)); //Don't mind the time.
    }
}

IEnumerator Delay(float waitTime) 
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (waitTime);
    if (Jumper != null) 
    {
        Jumper.SetVelocityToJump (gameObject, TimeToJump);
    }
}
```

Script 2 attached to player (cube):

```
public class Script2 : MonoBehaviour {

    GameObject target;
    private float timeToJump;
    public bool isJumping = false;

    public void SetVelocityToJump(GameObject goToJumpTo, float timeToJump)
    {
        StartCoroutine(jumpAndFollow(goToJumpTo, timeToJump));
        this.timeToJump = timeToJump;
        this.target = goToJumpTo;
    }

    private IEnumerator jumpAndFollow(GameObject goToJumpTo, float timeToJump)
    {
        var startPosition = transform.position;
        var targetTransform = goToJumpTo.transform;
        var lastTargetPosition = targetTransform.position;
        var initialVelocity = getInitialVelocity(lastTargetPosition - startPosition, timeToJump);

        var progress = 0f;
        while (progress < timeToJump)
        {
            progress += Time.deltaTime;
            if (targetTransform.position != lastTargetPosition)
            {
                lastTargetPosition = targetTransform.position;
                initialVelocity = getInitialVelocity(lastTargetPosition - startPosition, timeToJump);
            }

            float percentage = progress * 100 / timeToJump;  
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = percentage < 100.0f;  

            transform.position = startPosition + (progress * initialVelocity) + (0.5f * Mathf.Pow(progress, 2) * _gravity);
            yield return null;
        }

        OnFinishJump (goToJumpTo, timeToJump);
    }


    private void OnFinishJump(GameObject target, float timeToJump)
    {
        if (stillJumping)
        {
            this.isJumping = false;
        }
    }

    private Vector3 getInitialVelocity(Vector3 toTarget, float timeToJump)
    {
        return (toTarget - (0.5f * Mathf.Pow(timeToJump, 2) * _gravity)) / timeToJump;
    }
}
```

The target of the cube is a child of the bigger cube (the wall).

If you require clarification, please leave a comment below. I might give the link to my game if you need more details.

Quote from [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/55179/cheapest-way-to-catch-collisions-on-very-fast-movi.html) (found thanks to @Logman): "The problem exists even if you use continuous dynamic collision detection because fast moving objects can move so fast that they are too far apart from itself from one frame to the next immediate frame. It's like they teleported and no collision detection would ever be triggered because no collision existed, from each frame perspective, and thus from all calculations processed."

In my case, the cube is not going fast, but you get the concept.

Comment: Use FixedUpdate() and fix the actual bug ("undesired weird movement"). If the issue still happen to be there, enlarge collider on slow devices or set a minimum hardware req. or optimize the code if you can. Oh! And playing with fixed timestamp did now work because (not surprisingly) that's related to FixedUpdate() processing

Comment: Your outline "Delay" is wrong.  Simply use **Invoke** in Unity for timers.

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't using the built in collision events? If its just the undesired weird movements, then I agree with the other posters that they should be resolved. After, you can simply use FixedUpdate(), Continuous Dynamic collision detection, along with the standard Collision events built into MonoBehavior Object Model to achieve what you want. As an added benefit, if you setup your scene properly, you probably can save some resources by choosing simpler collision detection model. Your best bet is probably asking a different question about your "undesired weird movement."

Comment: You can't resolve this problem using unity physics engine. Look at this http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/55179/cheapest-way-to-catch-collisions-on-very-fast-movi.html

Comment: Yes, but that's a pretty rare occurrence. My real point was "is the implementation as designed _necessary?_" In other words, I agree that with very fast moving objects physics is not fast enough... but the original question doesn't state that there are fast moving objects. In fact, the original question states that its the _player_ which (ordinarily) would not be moving that fast.

Comment: Thats why the first question in my comment was _Is there a reason why you aren't using the built in collision events?_ Fast moving objects would be a good reason, but it wasn't explicitly stated. There are also other possible reasons that are actually not so good.

Answer (score 7):

There are several issues with your code.

1. You are asking a Coroutine to yield for 1/50th of a second. The minimum time a yield must occur for is one frame. If `Time.deltaTime > 0.02f` this is already one of the problems.
2. You are using Coroutines and `yield return null` to compute physics calculations. Essentially, you're computing physics in `Update()`, which is only called *once* per frame (`null` is equivalent to `new WaitForEndOfFrame()`: as mentioned in (1), a running Coroutine cannot be yielding between frames). Under low frame-rate, the amount of motion an object undertook between two frames might exceed the collision range of the target trigger. Assuming linear, non-accelerating motion: `∆S = v∆t` where v = velocity, ∆S is movement to cover in the current frame, ∆t is `Time.deltaTime`. As you can see, ∆S scales proportionally with ∆t.
3. You have `GetComponent<T>()` calls inside loops. Always avoid doing this: store a reference as a member variable instead (initialise it in `Start()`).

My suggestion for the quickest working hack would be to not worry too much about "being clean", and instead create subroutines that you call from `FixedUpdate()`, and (create and) use member `bool`s to conditionally test which subroutine to "execute" and which to "skip". You can also use member `bool`s or `enum`s as triggers to switch between various "states".

A better solution would be to let Unity handle the kinematics and you instead work with `rigidbody` mutators (and not `transform.position`s), but that may be totally unnecessary for an arcade situation, which yours might be. In that case stick to the hack above.

If you *really* want to control kinematics by hand, use an engine like SFML. A Particle System tutorial would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 4):

It's your float *percentage*, among other things.

"If isKinematic is enabled, Forces, collisions or joints will not affect the rigidbody anymore."

That's from the isKinematic page of Unity's documentation. You're setting it to true when progress hits 100. So at lower framerates, there'll be a sudden jump due to Time.deltaTime steps being a lot higher, progress is suddenly >= 100, isKinematic is set to true and the player is no longer affected by collisions.

I think you're going to have to rethink a lot of the code here and do some heavy optimisations. But the other posters have laid those out already, so I don't need to.

EDIT: Misunderstood the initial question, thought that it meant you were trying to detect collisions but your code wasn't always detecting them. Didn't realise it actually meant getting the collisions to occur in the first place.